# I have defeated the Wall of Flesh, unlocking hard mode. Why won't the Pwnhammer break Crimson Altars?

Tags: terraria

Is this a bug? I am unable to unlock the next tier of ore because I can't break a Crimson Altar.

(before you ask, YES, I have defeated the Wall of Flesh and I am on hard mode.)

Comment: If it doesn't break the Altar then what DOES happen when you hit it?

Comment: It does ~190 damage to me and nothing happens

Comment: Did you try reloading the world? Did you find hardmode enemies to absolutely make sure you're in hardmode?

Comment: Then are you in the same world that you beat the WoF in? If it _is_ the same world then it's probably a bug, in which case restart Terraria and see if that helps anything.

Also, are you using the Pwnhammer and not the one you may have had before beating WoF? Maybe you were holding shift but the weaker hammer was first in your inventory.

Comment: No, I'm using the pwnhammer that dropped from the wall of flesh. Yes, I am in the same world i killed the wall of flesh in. I have reloaded the world countless times and the same thing keeps happening.

Comment: And yes there are plenty of hard mode enemies all around

Comment: Hey hey hey, I just found an underwater crimson altar and i was able to destroy it. False alarm everyone, thank you very much for your input

Answer (score 7):

From your description it sounds like a bug.

My thought process to test it out would be as follows (until resolution was found).

- Kill the Wall of Flesh again.
- Create a new world and kill the Wall of Flesh.
- Create a new character and world and try again.
- Create a new character and world on a new mode type and then kill the Wall of Flesh.

Have you edited your game files in any way or attempted to cheat? Please don't take offense if you have not, but this is all I can think of.

Best of luck.